# BottomNavigationView with ViewPager

Tags: android

I have two items in bottomNavigationView: "next" and "previous", I want that if current image at viewpager is first, the "previous" option don't will be enable, and if we in last image "next" option changed the text to "finish"
I did something like this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
           // NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
          //  startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.action_previous:
            item.setEnabled(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0 );
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() -1);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_next:
           if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() -1){
               item.setTitle(getString(R.string.action_finish));
           }
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but it's wrong becuase if section performed after onNavigationItemSelected and also when back to first image from last "finish" title still appear

Any idea would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles to this, here is one way to achieve this. You have to enable/disable the menu item and in additional set it checkable. Assuming you have 3 menu items in the BottomNavigation and Prev is item 0, Next is item 2, here is code that would work...

```
        @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int index = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();        
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
               // NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
              //  startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.action_previous:
                if (0 != index) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index - 1, true);
                    if(1 == index) {
                        item.setEnabled(false);
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        item.setChecked(true);
                    } else {
                        item.setChecked(false);
                        item.setCheckable(false);
                    }
                    mNavigation.getMenu().getItem(2).setEnabled(true);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.action_next:
                if (mAdapterViewPager.getCount()-1 > index) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index + 1, true);
                    if(mAdapterViewPager.getCount()-2 == index) {
                        item.setTitle(getString(R.string.action_finish));              
                        item.setEnabled(false);
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        item.setChecked(true);
                    } else {
                        item.setChecked(false);
                        item.setCheckable(false);
                    }
                    mNavigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```